# On click trigger not keeping full animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, onclick, css-transitions

I am triggering an svg checmark with a button. The way I am doing it is setting the checkmark to `opacity:0;` and then once the button is clicked, adding a class `fadeIn` and putting the opacity to `opacity:1;`.

My issue is when the opacity is set to 0 the animation is altered. The full animation isn't showing. You can see this by taking the `opacity:0` out of the chechmark class and running the fiddle again.

My question is, how can I get this checkmark to trigger/display with the button while keeping the full animation sequence.

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gtb1avet/24/) The snippet isn't producing the checkmark, not sure why.

```js
$('#trigger').on('click', function () {
 $('.checkmark').addClass('fadeIn');
});
```

```css
.checkmark {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #0783a7;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.checkmark-circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #0783a7;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark-check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 70;
  stroke-dashoffset: 70;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 100px #0783a7;
  }
}


.fadeIn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="checkmark-text">All Templates Selected</div>
  <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
    <circle class="checkmark-circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
    <path class="checkmark-check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by running the `animation` rule on the required elements based on the addition of the `.fadeIn` class instead of placing it on the classes the elements have when they load. Try this:

```css
.checkmark {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    stroke-width: 5;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    margin: 10% auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #0783a7;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
}
.checkmark-circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 166;
    stroke-dashoffset: 166;
    stroke-width: 5;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke: #0783a7;
    fill: none;
}
.checkmark-check {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 70;
    stroke-dashoffset: 70;
}

.checkmark.fadeIn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}
.checkmark.fadeIn .checkmark-circle {
    animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark.fadeIn .checkmark-check {
    animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes scale {
    0%,
    100% {
        transform: none;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 100px #0783a7;
    }
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gtb1avet/26/)

Comment: Should I add all of the other animations from the other `checkmark-circle` and `checkmark-check` to the `fadeIn` class too? That still isn't running thr full animation. Do you know why this won't work in the snippet?

Comment: Ah yes, you need to run all the animations based on the `.fadeIn` class being added. I'll update the answer to show you a full implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I changed this to fadeIn the div wrap, but it doesn't even show? https://jsfiddle.net/gtb1avet/27/

Comment: That's because your CSS rules for the `.fadeIn` classes were missing spaces, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/gtb1avet/28/

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know why this isn't running in the snippet I made? I was using a previous example and modifying. I don't see any sort of external library?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - it seems fine for me in the last fiddle.

Comment: That may be due to the security restrictions SO uses.

Comment: Do you know why the event isn't triggering every time after the button is clicked?

Comment: That's because you only ever call `addClass()`. Successive clicks won't do anything as the element already has that class. If that's not the logic you need, I'd suggest starting a new question giving the full steps you want to have